# MSonline Active Directory Automatic login

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365

I am currently using Powershell to create a script that will essentially add a user and license automatically instead of using the GUI. I am currently using MSOnline and MsolService. What I am trying to do is have it automatically login instead of bringing up the login window. 
This the the Windows that pops up. I just need it to automatically fill in the credentials and continue.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the `-Credential` parameter? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn194123.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code!

```
 $User = “xxxxxx”
    $Pass = “xxxxxx”
    $Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($User,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Pass -AsPlainText -Force))
    Import-Module MSOnline
    Connect-MsolService -Credential $Cred
    $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $Cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
    Import-PSSession $Session
```